# html go back button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to achieve a condition that allows you to go back to the previous page and if the previous page does not exist, it will go back to defined page.

Right now, I'm using this method
`<a href="javascript:history.back()">Go back</a>`
Just to go back to the previous page if exists and it works perfectly. But if the user opens this page without previous page existing, I want the button to redirect them to a hard coded "main page".

Comment: how about sending a value if you come from a previous page then history.back works as usual but if user opens these pages separately and there is no value then send then to your main page

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: @JoshGarrison If the pages can be opened separately, then the wording "Go Back" will be confusing to the user if there's nothing to go back to. So you may also want to change the button text from "Go Back" to "Main Page" or something like that if there isn't a history.

Comment: there is a length property on the history object, you could check if length > 0 then show back link otherwise show go to main page link.